# How to get the text between a word and an equals sign and an equals sign and a value?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I am learning regular expressions in Java (technically the Android API) and have come across a problem. I was originally using basic functionality of Java's [`String.matchAll(String expression, String occurence);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) but now I use Pattern and Matcher classes.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to learn the basics and it seemed pretty simple.

My Java regex is `info(.*?)\\,` and I have also tried this: `(?<=\\binfo\\=).*?(?=\\=)`.

For the first regex if I had a string `"info i = 5,"` it would parse as `"info = 5"`. For the second one, if using the same string, I would get an exeption that there are no matches (InputMismatchException, I think).

My parsing code is:

```
//Produces "info i 5" rather than the desired "i"
public String parseStringAlias(String textToBeParsed)
{
    //Gets the value(or alias) located between the word info and the = sign
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("info(.*?)\\=");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(textToBeParsed);

    //0 would be the first match
    return m.group(0);
}

//Returns InputMismatchException rather than the desired number between equals sign and comma
//If given out example of "info i = 5," should return 5
public String parseStringValue(String textToBeParsed)
{
    //Pattern fetches the value between the "=" and the ","
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<==).*?(?=\\,)");

    //Search for matches
    Matcher m = p.matcher(textToBeParsed);

    //0 would be the first match
    return m.group(0);
}
```

Comment: You did not match anything because you do not run the regex search. Add `m.find()` before the return line. And it looks like you are seeking `.group(1)` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issues with your regexps: you should escape only special regex characters like `(`, `)`, `[`, etc. with `\\`, not with `//` and not such chracters as `,` or `=`.

You do not match anything because you do not "run" the regex search.

Add `m.find()` before each return line, better, use it inside an `if`. And it looks like you are seeking `.group(1)` value with `parseStringAlias` method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(parseStringAlias("\"info i = 5,\""));
    System.out.println(parseStringValue("\"info i = 5,\""));
}
//Produces "info i 5" rather than the desired "i"
public static String parseStringAlias(String textToBeParsed)
{
    //Gets the value(or alias) located between the word info and the = sign
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("info(.*?)="); // <- Note removed `//`
    Matcher m = p.matcher(textToBeParsed);
    //0 would be the first match
    if (m.find()) {                          // < - We "ran" the regex search
        return m.group(1);                   // <- Group 1 is accessed
    }
    return "";
}   

//Returns ImputMismatchException rather than the desired number between equals sign and comma
//If given out example of "info i = 5," should return 5
public static String parseStringValue(String textToBeParsed)
{
    //Pattern fetches the value between the "=" and the ","
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<==).*?(?=,)");          // <- Note removed `\\` and `//`
    //Search for matches
    Matcher m = p.matcher(textToBeParsed);
    //0 would be the first match
    if (m.find()) {                               // <- We "ran" the regex
        return m.group(0);                       // <- We access 0th group, the whole match
    }
    return "";
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/XQ5IlI)

Comment: I just noticed the incorrect // in my code after you pointed it out. Thanks. Simple typo since I am typing from my iPad (I do my coding on my computers, but I do not have access to my desktop or laptop for most of the day) and my original code is correct in that regard. I'll fix the escapes in my post. I based my logic for adding the escape character on the "+" and "-" as well as "<=" having special meanings. I'll run the code with the corrections and get back to you as soon as possible, thanks for the quick response.